# Create an array then sort data after ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to put data in array then sort it. Here is the sample JSON:

```
"region": {
    "BRA": {
      "activities": 24
    },
    "USA": {
      "activities": 58
    },
    "LUX": {
      "activities": 1
    },
```

This is what I have so far:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal" ng-repeat="(a,b) in content.regions">
      <dl class="dl-horizontal" ng-repeat="(c,d) in b">
            <dd class="wrap">{{a}} : {{d}} </dd>
      </dl>
</dl>
```

So far, I was able to show the region and activities. I need to sort "activities" by the highest number. Like this:

USA : 58

BRA : 24

LUX : 1

Comment: That data is not an array , it is an object and you can't sort objects. Map it to an actual arry in order to sort

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl! I'm a newbie in programming thus I really don't know how to create an array in angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

The region data that you are using must be an array / collection. You can define it as below -

```
$scope.regions = [{
    "name": "Brazil",
    "activities": 24
  }, {
    "name": "USA",
    "activities": 58
  }, {
    "name": "Luxembourg",
    "activities": 1
  }];
```

The html will then be something like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="region in regions">
 <td> {{region.name}} </td>
 <td> {{region.activities}} </td>
</tr>
```

And in order to sort it by highest number, you can use a javascript library like `underscore.js`

Here's a plunker solution to your problem
https://plnkr.co/edit/wJ2B1D8bphIJ9yfBtnS2